# Can I replace TRUNCATE + COPY + ANALYZE with TRUNCATE + COPY/FREEZE in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to optimize my bulk loading routine.

Currently I load data in steps (I am not following SQL syntax below, just the algorithm):

```
BEGIN
TRUNCATE table
COPY into table
ANALYZE table
COMMIT
```

Before `PostgreSQL 9.3` this was the only recommended way to re-load a table. Version `9.3` introduces `FREEZE` option that can be used with `COPY` command. Standard documentation says:

> FREEZE
>
> Requests copying the data with rows already frozen, just as
>   they would be after running the VACUUM FREEZE command. This is
>   intended as a performance option for initial data loading. Rows will
>   be frozen only if the table being loaded has been created or truncated
>   in the current subtransaction, there are no cursors open and there are
>   no older snapshots held by this transaction.

My immediate question is whether I still need to run `ANALYZE` after `COPY/FREEZE`. The standard doc doesn't give any direct recommendation on it. Would the following sequence suffice or do I still need to run `ANALYZE`?

```
BEGIN
TRUNCATE table
COPY/FREEZE table
COMMIT
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should still `ANALYZE` to force immediate table statistics generation after you `COPY` the data in.

Whether tuples are frozen or not has nothing to do with stats, it's a way to avoid later anti-wraparound vacuum activity.

Comment: It was wishful thinking on my part. That would be a nice feature though, it could save server resources if it could collect statistics as data is being loaded. Thanks Craig.

Comment: @cherio It'd be interesting to do that, yeah ... `COPY ... WITH STATISTICS`. Patches are welcome :p